# Classifying Algorithm for time series data

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have time series data(one instance of 30 seconds) as shown in the figure, I would like to know the what kind of classifying algorithms I could use.
[This is how the data looks in time and frequency domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kja8.png)

In the image we have 2 classes(one represented in blue and the other in orange).On the left section of the image we have data represented in the time-domain and on the right its equivalent Fourier-Transform.
I am thinking of using LSTM to train the data for both domains and also converting the above representations into an image and use CNNs to train.
Any Suggestion such as a better algorithm or a better representation of data would help.

Comment: Is the training set just these two signals exclusively?

Comment: Yes, the training set is a combination of the signal shown in blue and orange.There is only signal and I have represented the 2 different classes of that signal.

Answer (score 1):

One architecture suited to your needs is [WaveNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WaveNet).

The WaveNet architecture is constructed to deal with very long sequences (your sequences are reasonably long) and has been shown to outperform LSTM based RNNs on several tasks in [the original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.03499.pdf).

I am not sure what you mean by

> converting the above representations into an image and use CNNs to train

so I would suggest sticking to recurrent models or WaveNet for sequence classification.

Comment: After plotting the data using matplotlib, the plotted data is stored as an image(png,jpeg etc) and later these images are used to train the CNN. Is this sorta stupid?

Comment: Although this is possible, I would absolutely advise against this as it is unlikely to outperform sequence based models.